# Why does make oldconfig not work with a bash function?

Tags: bash, linux-kernel, make, function

I have the following function in my `bashrc`:

```
make() {
    nice -n 19 /usr/bin/make -j $(nproc) --output-sync "$@"
    echo -e "\a"
}
export -f make
```

The purpose is to run `make` on all threads, to sync the output and to “bell” when it is done.

This works fine for everything *except kernel config scripts*. Whenever I try to configure a kernel by running `make oldconfig` or `make menuconfig`, nothing is displayed:

```
$ make oldconfig
```

And then nothing happens. The behavior is the same for `make menuconfig`.
If I circumvent my function by calling `/usr/bin/make oldconfig`, it works.

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, I see the output:

```
TSX enable mode
> 1. off (X86_INTEL_TSX_MODE_OFF) (NEW)
  2. on (X86_INTEL_TSX_MODE_ON) (NEW)
  3. auto (X86_INTEL_TSX_MODE_AUTO) (NEW)
choice[1-3?]: make[1]: *** [scripts/kconfig/Makefile:69: oldconfig] Interrupt
make: *** [Makefile:534: oldconfig] Interrupt
```

My main terminal emulator is `st`, but I tried this in `xterm` and `gnome-terminal` as well, with no success.

Comment: What do you have as TERM?  Has stdout in any way been redirected?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I added infos regarding `TERM`. stdout is not redirected.

Comment: I figured out that this has nothing to do with tmux. I will update the question accordingly.

Comment: "stdout is not redirected", better have another look, at "man make" eg.